# Group similar values in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to group together similar tensor. For an example:

```
input: [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5]
output: [[1],[2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4,4],[5,5,5,5,5]]
```

I'm trying to use `unique_with_counts` and `split` functions but I'm getting error.
Here, is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

value = tf.constant([1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5])
y, idx, count = tf.unique_with_counts(value)
splitted = tf.split(value, count, 0)

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(splitted))
```

Following is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-161-aba9fdba9ef6> in <module>
      1 value = tf.constant([1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5])
      2 y, idx, count = tf.unique_with_counts(value)
----> 3 splitted = tf.split(value, count, 0)
      4 
      5 with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in split(value, num_or_size_splits, axis, num, name)
   1513       num = size_splits_shape[0]
   1514     if num is None:
-> 1515       raise ValueError("Cannot infer num from shape %s" % num_or_size_splits)
   1516 
   1517   return gen_array_ops.split_v(

ValueError: Cannot infer num from shape Tensor("UniqueWithCounts_6:2", shape=(?,), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: The result cannot be a tensor, the last dim has different shape. Do you want a list of tensor?

Comment: @zihaozhihao I want a tensor as output.

Comment: That's a invalid tensor because the first dim has different shapes.

Comment: @zihaozhihao what's the workaround to achieve same results ?

Comment: If you know how many unique elements will be in advance, you can add  `count.set_shape(5)` before you call `tf.split`.

Comment: Otherwise, you would better enable eager mode. `tf.enable_eager_execution()
`. It will work under eager mode.

Answer (score 2):

The solution given by @zihaozhihao worked for this particular case, but knowing the number of unique elements in advance is not always possible. But I knew the maximum no of unique elements in advance, so I used `dynamic_partition` as follows:

```
value = tf.constant([1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5])
y, idx, count = tf.unique_with_counts(value)
out = tf.dynamic_partition(value, idx, 10)
```

The output looks like this:

> [[array([1], dtype=int32), array([2, 2], dtype=int32), array([3, 3,
>   3], dtype=int32), array([4, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int32), array([5, 5, 5, 5,
>   5], dtype=int32), array([], dtype=int32), array([], dtype=int32),
>   array([], dtype=int32), array([], dtype=int32), array([],
>   dtype=int32)]]